# Find In Project regex not matching

Tags: kile

If I do this:

```
grep -ri "\.'" .
```

in a terminal to search for the literal .' (dot apostrophe) , it seems to work and returns some hits. However, inside of Kile, using the Find in Files or Find in Project functions which use grep it returns no hits (though searching other normal strings does work, so I know it is searching the right files). Is there a different way I could specify this string? I also tried

```
.'
\.\'
\\.\\'
".'"
"\.\'"
"\\.\\'"
```

but they did not work either.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe your system. GNU grep is not the same program as BSD grep for example. I have no idea how the regular expressions are implemented in Kile but it is definitely possible that Kile has different implementation then your system grep.

Comment: This looks very borderline for 'on topic', as TeX expertise will not really help. The detail of regex implementations is always somewhat complex (basically: each one is different), and the TeX link here is at best marginal.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac - I am on Ubuntu 12.04.

JosephWright - I only tagged the topic 'Kile', so I thought it was pretty relevant to that :). If it is not "tex" enough, feel free to delete it.